# Flutter get list values to another list

Tags: dart

I have a `List` in the following format:

```
List<ImageCollections> collectionlist;
```

It looks like this:

```
collectionlist = [
  { collectionname: 'abc', srcimage: url1, collectionimgnumber: 5, hreflink: link1 },
  { collectionname: 'xyz', srcimage: url2, collectionimgnumber: 4, hreflink: link2 },
  ...
];
```

Is there a way I can create a new `List` containing only the `srcimage` of each entry?

The new list should look like this:

```
newList = [ url1, url2, ... ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Iterable.map`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/map.html):

```
newList = collectionlist.map((object) => object.srcimage);
```

Comment: how can i take both values collectionname and srcimage

Comment: @HitanshuGogoi `(object) => { 'srcimage': object.srcimage, 'collectionname': object.collectionname }`

Answer (score 1):

Use the list map function:

```
srcimagelist = collectionlist.map((x) => x.srcimage);
```